# Retrieve the user id who posts a single entry of Gravity Form

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin

Suppose that I know the entry ID ($lead_id), how can I retrieve the user who creates that entry.

I try to

```
$lead = RGFormsModel::get_lead( $lead_id ); 
$form = GFFormsModel::get_form_meta( $lead['form_id'] ); 

$values= array();

foreach( $form['fields'] as $field ) {

    $values[$field['id']] = array(
        'id'    => $field['id'],
        'label' => $field['label'],
        'value' => $lead[ $field['id'] ],
    );
}
```

But the user data is not there. I check sql database, and the user data is in `wp_rg_lead` table, not in `wp_rg_lead_detail` table.

Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information in the *_rg_lead table is accessible in the array that's returned by the get_lead function. So

user_id = $lead['created_by']

Also note that it's better to use the Gravity Forms API for retrieving the entry, specifically the [get_entry function](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/api-functions/#get_entry):

GFAPI::get_entry( $entry_id )

which will return an [Entry object](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/entry-object/).